# How do I add the number of currently highlighted characters to the vim-airline plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

I'm in love with vim-airline (once I figured out how to configure it) but one thing I cannot figure out how to do is add the count of currently selected/highlighted characters to the bar. I'm hoping there is a configuration option for this in vim-airline. This is what my status bar looks like currently:

[image: My current status bar]

What I was trying to do was add a configuration variable to my .vimrc for vim-airline. The general format of the configuration line is:
`let g:airline_symbols.colnr = ' Ⅲ '`

I cloned the source and searched for a list of configuration options but didn't find anything that seemed to deal with what I need. Doesn't mean it's not there--there doesn't seem to be any list like this.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Honestly I have not figured out WHAT to try. I can't find a configuration value that I can set for this. I did manage to change the symbols and spacing in the right hand yellow section.  I know I can use g-<ctrl>g but that just shows it until I hit another key. I'd rather have it in the status bar